# Docker - Send multiple images to registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, continuous-deployment, docker-registry

I have a project that has 2 Dockerfiles; one for the frontend and another for the backend.
However in my local machine, I've created a `docker-compose.yml` file that will build the respective Dockerfiles inside respective folders and run them in the prescribed order

**Current structure**

```
.
+-- api
|   +-- Dockerfile
|   +-- ...
+-- frontend
|   +-- Dockerfile
|   +-- ...
+-- docker-compose.yml
```

So, locally the stack is started through `docker-compose up`. 
I'm now planning to get the entire stack into a private registry.

What would be the best way to get the images up, making it easy for dev and CI/CD routines?

1. Can each `Dockerfile` images pushed individually and pulled into a new server? or
2. Is there a way the different images can be combined to one and used?

or let me know the most efficient method to deploy this.

Comment: Have you already tried ˋdocker-compose pushˋ?

Comment: yeah. was wondering how to push it to a private registry. ˋdocker-compose pushˋ tries to push it to docker hub inspite logging in with a private registry

Comment: You need to login first with ˋdocker loginˋ and then you need to retag your images to contain the full path of your registry otherwise they get pushed to docker hub as you already noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To push multiple images that are build by your compose you can use [`docker-compose push`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/push/) command. Remember that image names in your compose should be in appropriate format. Your docker compose could look like :

```
version: '3'
services:
  sv1:
    build: .
    image: localhost:4000/imgename:tag  # for local registry

  sv2:
    build: .
    image: hubusername/imagename:tag  # for DockerHub registry
```

With this command you can push all images at once, but you can also specify service name, whose image you want to push. You can then download those images from your repository separately.